# cURL auth "400 Bad Request: The SSL certificate error"

Tags: php, nginx, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I have two debian servers with nginx and php. Server 1 acts as a 'client', Server 2 as a 'server'.
The 'server' has a REST API and I try to authenticate the 'client' against the 'server' with the following script.

```
    $data   = json_encode(
        [
            "name"      => '<username>',
            "password"  => '<password>',
        ]
    );

    $url = BASIC_URL."/authenticate/v1";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, ROOT_PATH . '/config/certificates/client.crt');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, ROOT_PATH . '/config/certificates/client.key');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch);
```

I've created the certificates with the following

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out ca.key -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out ca.crt -subj "/C=<country>/ST=<state>/L=<town>/O=<company>/CN=<domain_from_server>"

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out client.key -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj "/C=<country>/ST=<state>/L=<town>/O=<company>/CN=<domain_from_client>"
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 365

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out server.key -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj "/C=<country>/ST=<state>/L=<town>/O=<company>/CN=<domain_from_server>"
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

my nginx config from the 'server' look like this

```
server {
    server_name <domain_from_server> www.<domain_from_server>;

    root <path_to>/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    rewrite ^/index\.html$ /index.php last;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # SSL-Konfigurationen
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain_from_server>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain_from_server>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain_from_server>/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot


    ssl_client_certificate /var/www/<domain_from_server>/<path_to>/ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional;
}

server {
    if ($host = <domain_from_server>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name <domain_from_server> www.<domain_from_server>;
    root <root_path>;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    rewrite ^/index\.html$ /index.php last;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

using the following, i recieve the same md5

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in client.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in client.key | openssl md5
```

using `openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt client.crt` just gives a `client.crt: OK`

The `/var/log/nginx/error.log` does not says anything relevant.
I only have the following error message "400 Bad Request - The SSL certificate error"

[image]

...any ideas?

Comment: Might be missing key usage in the client certificate. See https://serverfault.com/questions/875229/two-way-ssl-error-400-the-ssl-certificate-error-just-for-client-certificate

Comment: That seemed to be ok. But...i didn't change anything yesterday and for some reasons it is working today. I am still investigating, maybe some cache thingys?..